# How to get all SMS in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing an application on Xamarin Forms. I need to get all messages from the device, is this possible and how?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT unfortunately no, in Xamarin.Android method Query in ContentResolver isn't static. I tried to create an instance of ContentResolver but it is an abstract class :(

Comment: What's the issue you're having ? It works on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple sample that you could get the sms in your device.

```
string[] items;
public void getAllSms()
    {

        string INBOX = "content://sms/inbox";
        string[] reqCols = new string[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type" };
        Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(INBOX);
        var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, reqCols, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String messageId = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[0]));
                String threadId = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[1]));
                String address = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[2]));
                String name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[3]));
                String date = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[4]));
                String msg = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[5]));
                String type = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[6]));

                items = new string[] {
       ((messageId + (","
                        + (threadId + (","
                        + (address + (","
                        + (name + (","
                        + (date + (" ,"
                        + (msg + (" ," + type))))))))))))) };

            } while (cursor.MoveToNext());

        }
    }
```

if your device android version higher than 5,you need rquest runtime permission.

```
RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadSms }, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, I solved a problem with ContentResolver. I had to use
Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query to get the Cursor data